# How can I subdivide a column in Semantic UI?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I want to be able to subdivide a column in Semantic UI. So it would look like the following. Where I have restricted the large are to being only 12 columns wide:

[image]

Issue is, any columns within that column just get thrown under it as new rows. How can I either subdivide the column, or otherwise achieve this effect?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9j6etua/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui centered grid">
    <div class="column four wide"> </div>
    <div class="column four wide"> </div>
    <div class="column four wide"> </div>
    <div class="column twelve wide">
      <div class="column six wide"> </div>
      <div class="column three wide"> </div>
      <div class="column four wide"> </div>
      <div class="column six wide"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Updated JSFiddle showing additional issues: https://jsfiddle.net/b9j6etua/16/

The end result I'm aiming for is being able to specify the columns form inputs are in inside of a form.

Edit2: If the premises of my question is fundamentally incorrect (ie. `"You shouldn't even be trying to subdivide columns, use this: instead"`) please let me know. I can only explain my problem with the knowledge I currently have of Semantic UI.

I will mark this as answered and ask another more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a way that will work for you?

Here is an update of [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9j6etua/4/), ...

... and here is a code snippet.

```css
.column:not(.row):not(.grid):after {
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .01);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2) inset;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui centered grid">
    <div class="column four wide"> </div>
    <div class="column four wide"> </div>
    <div class="column four wide"> </div>
    <div class="column four wide"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui centered grid">  
    <div class="column six wide"> </div>
    <div class="column six wide"> </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="ui centered grid">    
    <div class="column five wide"> </div>
    <div class="column seven wide"> </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="ui centered grid">
    <div class="column ten wide"> </div>
    <div class="column two wide"> </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sure this will, I will give it a try in a bit and mark it as the answer if this satisfies my need. Thank you!

Comment: Sadly that does not work. I still need to specify a column to use a form and attached message. When I try and use an attached message inside of a grid it does not turn out. https://jsfiddle.net/b9j6etua/16/

Comment: Thanks LGSon, the example for #16 of the jsfiddle was meant to show that outside of a column it doesn't line up. I want to be able to column the items inside of the form, which means I either need to be able to subdivide the inside of the 14 wide column, or utilize something else. I can't use columns inside of a `text container` either. I hope this will clear up my question for you. I may just be trying to about this in the entirely wrong way as well.

Comment: @douglasg14b As my answer solves the initial layout you asked, it would be appropriate to accept that for this question, then create and post a new one with the "column the items of a form" and we can help with that.